# Правильно ли я составил схему генерации динамической веб страницы?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Составил схему генерации динамической страницы. Хотел узнать: 1)правильно ли? 2)если да, то правильно ли то, что я отнёс только разработку CSS и JavaScript файлов к Frontend? Или Frontend разработчик занимается не только разработкой этих файлов в динамических веб страницах?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1)веб браузер отправляет запрос веб серверу на получения веб страницы (например index.php)
2)веб сервер считывает этот файл, "осознаёт" , что это php сценарий,
запускает интерпретатор, который обеспечивает выполнение этого php сценария
3)интерпретатор интерпретирует файл php сценария
4)в коде php сценария написан код для обращения к СУБД.
СУБД отправляются запросы на доступ к определённым данным БД
5)СУБД обрабатывает запросы
6)происходит интерпретация php сценария,
в результате чего создаётся html файл(веб страница) и в html файл добавляются данные из БД
7)файл с html кодом связан с файлами с JS и CSS с помощью тегов html
8)веб сервер отправляет html файл браузеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша схема правильна для подхода с серверным рендерингом `HTML`, то есть `SSR`. В случае, если на фронтенде используются фреймворки, которые позволяют делать SPA-приложения, то схема почти индентична, но немного другая:

1. Юзер отправляет запрос на сервер за статическими файлами
2. Браузер получает пустой HTML и большой JS-бандл, который браузер парсит и выполняет, при помощи JS в DOM добавляются все элементы приложения, которые также могут отправлять запросы на API-edpoint серверной части
3. С клиента снова отправляется запрос для получения данных (как раз здесь может быть запрос к PHP и вся та же схема его обработки с БД), а пока он выполняется на клиенте отображается загрузка. Данные возвращаются с сервера в `JSON`-формате
4. После получения данных приложение на клиенте парсит `JSON` и получает необходимые данные, которые отображает